# Checkmark multiple rows by loading NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, checkmark

I'm asking the user to select options in a UITableView and then saving the selection in `NSUserDefaults`. I'm making sure that if the user selects an option twice, it gets added only once..i.e no duplicates.

I'm loading the `NSUserDefaults` and then trying to show the rows as "checked"..so that the user remembers what he/she had selected when they had run the app earlier.

Now, I know that only the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method can set a checkmark. 
The below code only checkmarks the last object. But how do I get multiple checkmarks?

This is how far I've gotten.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
appSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.title = @"Select News Categories";
_selectedCategoriesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self initNewsCategories];
[self loadNewsSelectedCategories];
}
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [_newsCategoriesArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellNewsCategory" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_newsCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSString * cellText = [[cell textLabel] text];
for (NSString * lbl in _selectedNewsCategories)
{
    if ([cellText isEqualToString:lbl])
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

}
return cell;
}
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
UITableViewCell * selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString * selectedCategory = [[selectedCell textLabel] text];
if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedCategory);
    [_selectedCategoriesArray addObject:selectedCategory];
    NSLog(@"_selectedCategoriesArray:%@", _selectedCategoriesArray);
    [appSettings setObject:_selectedCategoriesArray forKey:@"selectedNewsCategories"];

}
else if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedCategory);
    [_selectedCategoriesArray removeObject:selectedCategory];
    NSLog(@"_selectedCategoriesArray:%@", _selectedCategoriesArray);
    [appSettings setObject:_selectedCategoriesArray forKey:@"selectedNewsCategories"];
}
else
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
[appSettings synchronize];
}
#pragma mark Helper methods
-(void) initNewsCategories
{
_newsCategoriesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Arts",@"Business",@"Company",
                        @"Entertainment",@"Environment",@"Health",@"Lifestyle",
                        @"Media",@"Money",@"Most Read",@"Trending",@"World",nil];
}
-(void) loadNewsSelectedCategories
{
_selectedNewsCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_selectedNewsCategories = [appSettings objectForKey:@"selectedNewsCategories"];

}
```

Comment: Does your table allow multiple selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in this code:

```
for (NSString * lbl in _selectedNewsCategories)
{
    if ([cellText isEqualToString:lbl])
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

}
```

You first checkmark cell but then you continue search and unmark cell.
You need to use this:

```
for (NSString * lbl in _selectedNewsCategories)
{
    if ([cellText isEqualToString:lbl])
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

}
```

Or this

```
if([_selectedNewsCategories indexOfObject: cellText] != NSNotFound)
{
  [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}else
{
  [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```